# SQL Server : join of three tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

We were creating a WPF application project on billing and stock maintenance. In the database a table `tbl_puv` contains purchase details product id, quantity and scale id, receipt table `tbl_receipt` receipt is put for required quantity. After each receipt I should update `tbl_puv` of the remaining quantity of the product.

This is the query I use:

```
SELECT 
    Pending = (([Convertscale](tbl_puv.Quantity, tbl_puvd.ScaleId, p.StandardUnit)) - ([Convertscale](tbl_reciptdetails.Quantity, tbl_reciptdetails.Scale, p.StandardUnit))) 
FROM 
    dbo.tbl_Product p 
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.tbl_puvd ON p.ProductId = dbo.tbl_puv.ProductId 
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.tbl_reciptdetails ON tbl_reciptdetails.ProductId = tbl_puvd.ProductId 
tbl_puv.IsActive = 'True' AND tbl_receiptdetails.IsActive = 'True' AND tbl_puvd.PurchaseId = 10609
```

where `Convertscale` is scalar-valued function to convert unit of product to standard unit before subtraction

In the above query, my tables are:

- `tbl_puv`---purchase table
- `tbl_puvd` ---purchase details table
- `tbl_receiptdetails` --- receipt details table
- `tbl_product` --- product table

I am getting multiple results please help me with the query....Thank you

The tables are structured with columns as follows:

```
tbl_PIVD = pivID | prodID | Qty |  ScaleID

tbl_GRN = gID | pivID 

tbl_GRND = grndID | gID | prodID | Qty | ScaleID 

tbl_prod = prodID | ScaleID(SIunit)
```

Problem: to get the quantity(Qty) and its difference 
pending = ConvertScale(tbl_PIVD.Qty, tbl_PIVD.ScaleID, tbl_prodID.ScaleID ) 
- ConvertScale(tbl_GRND.Qty, tbl_GRND.ScaleID, tbl_prodID.ScaleID )
from the tbl_PIVD and tbl_GRND table where tbl_PIVD.pivID= tbl_GRN.pivID and 
tbl_PIVD.prodID = tbl_GRND.prodID. Subtraction is done after making the both scale equal, scale is converted using a function ConvertScale

Comment: Please show us the results you're getting now, and he results you actually want

Comment: I think, You missing mapping between tbl_puv and tbl_puvd tables. Mention Table definitions for more clarification.

Comment: Would you mind proof reading your question and formatting your code? Is "purchase details product id" one field or 3 or 4 seperate fields depending on the readers interpretation?

Comment: Your query is incomplete - what is that last line?? Are those *additional JOIN* criteria and should be added with an extra `AND` - or are those general filter criteria that should have a `WHERE` at their beginning? .....

Comment: sir i have re-posted the information pls check and answer

Comment: hi, after your second inner join, is there a where clause ?

Comment: hi, i dont know whether my query is correct or not.. hence i defined the problem.... hope if i can get new query

Answer (score 0):

i have tried to edit your query:

```
 declare @pending as numeric(18,2)
    SELECT 
      top 1 @pending = isnull((([Convertscale](tbl_puv.Quantity, tbl_puvd.ScaleId, 
     p.StandardUnit)),0.00) - isnull(([Convertscale](tbl_reciptdetails.Quantity, tbl_reciptdetails.Scale, p.StandardUnit))),0.00) 
FROM 
    dbo.tbl_Product p 
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.tbl_puvd ON p.ProductId = dbo.tbl_puv.ProductId 
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.tbl_reciptdetails ON tbl_reciptdetails.ProductId = tbl_puvd.ProductId 
where
tbl_puv.IsActive = 'True' AND tbl_receiptdetails.IsActive = 'True' AND tbl_puvd.PurchaseId = 10609 

select @pending
```